# What javascript libs & frameworks are integrated in WordPress vanilla?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering what JavaScript libraries and frameworks are integrated in WordPress, which I could use out of the box?
Also wondering if I can see which versions of the libs and frameworks are used per WordPress version?
Is there any good documentation to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the list of scripts and their registered handles here:

[Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)

You can also search in `wp-includes/js` and `wp-admin/js` directories.